# Populating a Data Grid in WPF

Tags: .net

I need to populate a data grid with information from a table. Can anyone help me out on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Linq2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) and [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Right now that's about the best information I can provide. If you were to give more information about what you are trying to do and things that you have tried, then you can get more specific help with your problem.